# How to convert an numpy array of string array to nested numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of the format: `test = array(['[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]', '[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]'], dtype='<U17')`. I would like to convert it to numpy array of shape `(2,2,3)`.
Expected outcome is:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4]],
       
        [[2, 3, 4],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

Currently, I achieve this by doing - `np.array(list(map(lambda x: json.loads(x),test)))`.
I wonder if there's a better way to do this. Any pointers please?

Comment: `np.array([*map(ast.literal_eval, test)])` or just map the `json.loads` function directly, there's no need for a lambda: `np.array([*map(json.loads, test)])`

Comment: Where is your data coming from and why is it in this format?

Comment: @ddejohn I'm fetching it from hive. The column is in array<array<double>> dtype. Upon read, I get it in string array format.

Comment: That sounds like you're doing something wrong when you read it, and you should fix the problem there, not in post-processing.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica client sdk reads all columns in string format. I'm not doing anything there.